# split a string in velocity Template and access it by index in velocity

Tags: java, velocity

I am trying to split a string in velocity using split() given below:

```
#foreach ($element in $string.split(":"))
    #if($velocityCount >1)
    #foreach ($var in $element.split(","))
    #if($velocityCount ==1)
    @Param("$var") String $var,
#end
#end
#end
#end
```

I want to store the splitted string in an array and want to access it by index as we do in java.

```
String s[]=str.split(".");
s[0];
```

Is there anything similar to above java code in velocity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am pasting from the [velocity user guide](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html):

> All array references are treated as if they are fixed-length lists.
>   This means that you can call java.util.List methods and properties on
>   array references.

So in your case, to get the first element of the array after you split the string, you could just do:

```
#set ($s = $string.split(":"))
$s.get(0)
```

Comment: True, but only valid since Velocity 1.7.